# Citation for the result of variance of quadratic form

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, quadratic-forms, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I have seen it expressed that for the quadratic form;

$$ ()=^T+^⊤+ $$

for symmetric $A$, and where $x$ follows multivariate normal,

$$ ∼N(,Σ),  \quad ^⊤=. $$

then,
$$ Var[()]=2Tr(ΣΣ)+4^⊤Σ+4^⊤Σ+^⊤Σ $$

But I'm struggling to find a publication that contains the proof as a citation. Can anyone help?

Comment: seems here has a simpler form https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf

Comment: Can you specify the section. Looked for an equivalent but could not find a specific comparison that was not a concentration, or used different assumption?